# calling notifyDataSetChanged() makes multiple time execution of getView()

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am using customized `BaseAdapter` to show the listdata, whenever there is change in listitem I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it makes multiple calls to `getView()` method, I have given `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to the `ListView`. It will solve my problem if it gets invoked only single time for every `notifyDataSetChanged()` call.

Comment: could you show your listview implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my mistake. I did not update `ListView` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in different layout files like `layout-hdpi` etc

Comment: can you please explain the solution, as i am facing the same problem ?